# trying to send file using QNetworkAccessManager get() but not QNetworkAccessManager post()

Tags: c++, qt

I am a newbie, I am trying to send a .xml file to server using Qt4.8. My restriction is , I am told to use `QNetworkAccessManager->get()` only. Although `QNetworkAccessManager->post` is available but I can't use it as per instruction given to me. So, write following code:-

```
bool PIS::sendPISData(QString xmlFile,QString IP)
{
    QFile xmlfyle(xmlFile);
    if(!xmlfyle.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        #ifdef DEBUG
        qDebug("Can not open file device.");
        #endif
    }

    QString content = (QString)xmlfyle.readAll();
    xmlfyle.close();
    QNetworkAccessManager mgr;
    QEventLoop eventLoop;
    QUrl url(QString("http://"+IP+"/Smart_Coach_Service/data_interchange/senddata"));

    QNetworkRequest reqpn(url);

    reqpn.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
    reqpn.setRawHeader("Content-Length",QByteArray::number(content.toUtf8().size()));
    reqpn.setRawHeader("Content-Data",content.toUtf8());
    QNetworkReply *replyn = mgr.get(reqpn);
    connect(replyn, SIGNAL(finished()), &eventLoop, SLOT(quit()));
    eventLoop.exec(); // blocks stack until "finished()" has been called
    return true;
}
```

But I am not getting anything on server side. I want to know what exactly I am missing here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error in uploading XML file on server using QT 4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51440942/error-in-uploading-xml-file-on-server-using-qt-4-8)

Comment: It's not a duplicate question. both question was raised by me. In previous one, I was trying to send file using post() function, but now I ma trying to use get()

Comment: is the same question, your goal is the same, you must edit your previous question and add that you have tried to get, I still doubt that it works with get since it is used to obtain data, not to create it.

Comment: yeah, You are right

Comment: I recommend you read about the CRUD so that you understand the difference between the different petitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out, you have to add data as query. code will like this:-

```
bool PIS::sendPISData(QString xmlFile,QString IP)
{
    QFile xmlfyle(xmlFile);
    if(!xmlfyle.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        #ifdef DEBUG
        qDebug("Can not open file device.");
        #endif
    }

    QString content = (QString)xmlfyle.readAll();
    #ifdef DEBUG
    qDebug()<<"content :::  "<<content;
    #endif
    xmlfyle.close();
    QNetworkAccessManager mgr;
    QEventLoop eventLoop;
    QUrl url(QString("http://"+IP+"/Smart_Coach_Service/data_interchange/senddata"));
    url.addQueryItem("xml_data", content);
    QNetworkReply *replyn = mgr.get(reqpn);
    connect(replyn, SIGNAL(finished()), &eventLoop, SLOT(quit()));
    eventLoop.exec(); 
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to read more about HTTP. Despite there is a chance to send a data in a custom header (like your `"Content-Data"`) with a BASE64 encoding (HTTP does not allow raw UTF8 in headers), it's a so called **BAD PRACTICE**. Do not do so!